# KeystoneJS 'resolveInput' field hook: returning 'resolvedData' from field hook produces GraphQL cast error

Tags: graphql, keystonejs

I'm trying to modify data on save of a particular field in KeystoneJS 5.  The [`resolveInput` field hook](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/hooks#resolveinput) seems a good way to do this.  It's the example that's given in the docs above:

```
const resolveInput = ({
  operation,
  existingItem,
  originalInput,
  resolvedData,
  context,
  actions,
}) => {
  // Input resolution logic
  // Object returned is used in place of resolvedData
  return resolvedData;
};
```

> The return of resolveInput can be a Promise or an Object. It should
>   resolve to the same structure as the resolvedData. The result is
>   passed to the next function in the execution order.

Thus, the definition of the field in my list is

```
text: {
                type: Wysiwyg,
                hooks: {
                    async resolveInput({ originalInput,resolvedData }) {
                        console.log('resolvedData');
                        console.log(resolvedData);
                        return resolvedData;
                    }
                }
```

and to get started I'm just returning the `resolvedData` argument that's passed in, which, according to the docs is

```
resolvedData    Object  The data received by the GraphQL mutation plus defaults values
```

However, I get the following error every time

```
GraphQLError
Cast to string failed for value "{ text: '<p><img src="static/blop.jpg" alt="" width="580" height="388" /><img src="static/blop.jpg" alt="" /></p>' }" at path "text"
```

I'm unsure what the issue is or how to solve it -- I'm simply returning the same data that's passed in.  When I remove the hook, all works fine.

### Edit

I believe the answer is that one *does not* return the entire `resolvedData` object, but instead the *field* on that object whose hook you are in.  Thus, in the case below, one would return `resolvedData.text` (or `resolvedData.title`).  I believe the docs could be improved, since it would seem that one returns the entire `resolvedData` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: according to the code in @keystonejs/keystone/lib/List/index.js one should return from *resolveInput* hook the ***field*** object rather than the whole *resolvedData* object:

```
    // Run the schema-level field hooks, passing in the results from the field
// type hooks
resolvedData = {
  ...resolvedData,
  ...(await this._mapToFields(
    this.fields.filter(field => field.hooks.resolveInput),
    field => field.hooks.resolveInput({ ...args, resolvedData })
  )),
};
```

The returning value is assigned to the ***field*** element inside *resolvedData* object where *resolveInput* hook is defined.